# morris line date axis repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, morris.js

My problem is about x (date) axis repetition. If I retrieve monthly data in a year range (12 units of data), Morris line illustrates the chart well. But, if I retrieve data in three or four months range (4 units of data), it causes x axis repetition.

Chart for a year:
[image: Chart for a year]

Chart for four months:
[image: Chart for four months]

Here is my code to initialize the chart:

```
var graphData = [];
var majorCount = 0;
var minorCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    graphData.push({ period: result[i].Date + '', MAJOR: parseInt(result[i].Text), MINOR_MAJOR: parseInt(result[i].Title) + parseInt(result[i].Text) });
    majorCount += parseInt(result[i].Text);
    minorCount += parseInt(result[i].Title);
}

$("#div-ariza-turu").html('');

window.ariza_turu = Morris.Line({
    element: 'div-ariza-turu',
    data: graphData,
    lineColors: ['#4099ff', '#E67A77'],
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['MINOR_MAJOR', 'MAJOR'],
    labels: ['MINOR + MAJOR', 'MAJOR'],
    //redraw: true,
    //resize: true,
    resize: false,
    redraw: false,
    xLabelFormat: function (date) {
        return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    },
    yLabelFormat: function (y) { return y != Math.round(y) ? '' : y; },
    dateFormat: function (date) {
        d = new Date(date);
        return (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
    }
});
```

Comment: I suppose your `result` variable contains these duplicates. Could you provide the code that retrieves the data? And show what contains `result` with a four months range?

Comment: Thank you for attention. The problem was solved. parseTime attribute should has been false.